# Upload a .zip file to ArcGIS Enterprise Portal using Python

Tags: python, publishing, arcgis-enterprise

I am attempting to upload/publish a .zip file containing a shapefile to ArcGIS Enterprise Portal. The goal is to create a base script in python doing this in order to eventually iterate through multiple files for upload. The catch is that I need to develop a script that can be used by users who don't have access to ESRI licensing. In other words, I need to be able to do this without using the arcpy and GIS modules. Does anyone know how this can be accomplished or can someone point me towards some documentation to complete this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ArcGIS API for Python which [does not need ArcGIS Pro to be installed](https://www.esri.com/about/newsroom/arcuser/harness-the-power-of-gis-with-the-arcgis-api-for-python/). However, same as with using ArcGIS REST API directly, you'll need credentials or a token to access your Portal for ArcGIS.

You can install ArcGIS API for Python using `conda` (e.g. Anaconda or Miniconda) or `pipenv`. See also [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/install-and-set-up/).

```
conda install arcgis -c esri
```

Here is an example of a script:

```py
from arcgis.gis import GIS  # conda install arcgis -c esri

shapefile = r"clip_area.zip"

gis = GIS("<URL TO THE PORTAL>", "<USERNAME>", "<PASSWORD>")

file = gis.content.add(
    item_properties = {
        "type": "Shapefile", 
        "title": "Clip Area",
        "description": "Just a random Study Area",
        "tags": "Clip Area, Study Area",
    },
    data = shapefile,
)
```

The script above adds a shapefile to your portal. Here are some related links:

- [`arcgis.gis.GIS`](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.gis.toc.html#gis)
- [`arcgis.gis.ContentManager.add`](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.gis.toc.html#arcgis.gis.ContentManager.add)
- [List of Content Types](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/users-groups-and-items/items-and-item-types.htm)

Note: You can also use a token instead of username/password: `GIS(token="<YOUR TOKEN>")`. However, there are some caveats such as it is only honoured if security of the site uses BUILT-IN security. Find more [here (look for the parameter `token`)](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.gis.toc.html#arcgis.gis.GIS).

---

If you want to publish the file as well, you could do:

```py
feature_layer = file.publish(
    publish_parameters = {
        "hasStaticData": "true",
        "name": "Clip Area",
    },
    file_type = "Shapefile",
)
```

- [`arcgis.gis.Item.publish`](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.gis.toc.html#arcgis.gis.Item.publish)

---

Note: If you cannot install ArcGIS API for Python, then your best bet is to use the REST API as suggested by Marco Aurélio Reliquias in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

The ArcGIS Enterprise REST API can Upload files

[check the official Documentation.](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/enterprise/upload.htm)

You need get a token with a named user from Portal and use this token to send the files.

Comment: Could you give me a sample script for this? I have read that documentation before, but am just not sure how to follow through.